# Can people access my iphone data by opening it up

Tags: iphone, security

My iphone is faceid and pin protected. My apple id is two step authentication on.

It's not working now, so I sent it to a repair man to fix. However, If he opens up the phone, and takes out the storage chip. Can he use that storage on another phone of his ?

Comment: If you are concerned about your data privacy... you can lock your device via iCloud until you get your device back.   The chip containing your data will still be encrypted on a different device.

Answer (score 1):

Highly unlikely, unless the repair man:

- Sent your device to Cellbrite
- Has access to a GrayKey box
- Knows your passcode

Given the intertwined relationship between the iPhone's storage, baseband, Secure Enclave etc. (refer to Jash's answer), hypothetically speaking the repair man has a better chance at extracting your data if he left the storage chip in its place.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the following links to understand more about Data Protection and Secure Enclave on iOS Devices

1. [Data Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/security/secf6276da8a/web)
2. [Secure Enclave](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/security/sec59b0b31ff/1/web/1)

Comment: While interpreting the information on the links correctly may lead to the answer the OP is looking for it might be more helpful to actually summarize the information found there to provide an answer directly :-)